# How do I create a powershell script to pull active directory usernames, account they are a member of and lastlogondate?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This is what I have so far but I'm having no luck. What do you all think?

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*)" -SearchScope Subtree `
  -SearchBase "OU=adminaccounts,OU=Managed Objects,DC=testdomain,DC=Com" ` |
  % {
    $user = $_
    $user | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | 
    Select @{N="User";E={$user.sAMAccountName}},
           @{N="Group";E={$_.Name}},
           @{N="Last‌​Logon";E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.LastLogon)}}
  } |
  Select User,Group,LastLogon |
  Export-Csv C:\temp\report.csv -nti
```

Comment: We think that you need to be more specific about "no luck".

Comment: I apologize I'm still new to powershell. The script outputs everything but the lastlogondate.

Comment: Ok adjustments were made. I edited the script above in the original question to what you recommended. Unfortunately it gives me the same result. User and group is displayed but lastlogon is not.

Comment: This is getting tedious. Please read my answer again. I suggested **two** changes. Did I tell you to remove the first one when adding the second? Why did you remove it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`LastLogon` is not among the properties that [`Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) returns by default, unlike `Name` and `SamAccountName`. You need to explicitly tell the cmdlet to include that property:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(name=*)" -SearchScope Subtree `
  -SearchBase "OU=adminaccounts,OU=Managed Objects,DC=testdomain,DC=Com" `
  -Properties LastLogon | ...
```

Also replace `$_.LastLogon` with `$user.LastLogon` inside the first `select` statement, because the current object variable (`$_`) in the nested pipeline has a different value than you expect (the principal group of the user):

```
... | select ...,@{N="Last‌​Logon";E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.LastLogon)}}
```

Comment: Would I place that before the current script?

Comment: @JeremySmith You would modify your current script. There's a reason why a part of the above snippet is emphasized in bold.

Comment: I added the changes your recommended for the first script. What do you think?

Comment: I tried the script though and it still only returns the username and group membership